# Can a domain administrator read my search queries?

Tags: privacy, google

Google's [privacy policy](https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/) states that they log your search queries. They also state that domain administrators have access to your Google Account information (e-mail and "other data") as well as information stored as part of your account. Barring something like a law enforcement investigation, can the domain administrator arbitrarily read my search queries?

N.B The domain administrator's privacy policy links to Google's privacy policy.

Comment: Am I correct that you work for a company that uses Google business for email?

Comment: @NeilSmithline Something like that, yes.

Comment: This is more of a question for Google than for us.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to discuss specifics with Google and your domain admin, especially since much depends on the exact set up of you apps account, but it is a safe assumption that the domain administrator will be able to see almost as much as google can when it comes to your apps account activity. After all, they're paying for it.

(Also, good chance they are paying for the network and the computer you're using as well, so they may well be able to see everything being done with those resources as well.